# subprocess.CalledProcessError: returned non-zero exit status 1, while os.system does not raise any error

Tags: python, subprocess, newman

Given the following command:

```
newman run tests.postman_collection.json -e environment.json  --reporters testrail,json,html
```

Raises:

```
RuntimeError: command 'newman run tests.postman_collection.json -e environment.json  --reporters testrail,json,html
' return with error (code 1): b'\nhttps://host.testrail.io/index.php?/runs/view/1234\n'
```

Py code that executes the command:

```
        try:
            newmanCLI_output = subprocess.check_output(npmCLi, shell=True).decode().strip()
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

And yes I do use the check_output return.

The output is a url to test rail reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a misfeature of `os.system`; it returns the exit code so you can examine it, but doesn't raise an error if something fails.

The `check` in `subprocess.check_output` means check that the command succeeded, or raise an exception otherwise. This is generally a good thing, as you don't want processes to die underneath you without a warning.

But you can work around it with `subprocess.run` if you want to disable it;

```
import shlex
result = subprocess.run(shlex.split(npmCLi), text=True, capture_output=True)
newmanCLI_output = result.stdout
```

The switch to [avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) and use `shlex.split` to parse the string instead is not crucial, but hopefully demonstrates how to do these things properly.

You should still understand why exactly your command fails, and whether it is safe to ignore the failure.

Comment: It makes sense, using ur implementation raises file not found error tho :
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: Oh, Windows? How horrible. Maybe just replace the `shlex.split()` with the plain string, though still don't add `shell=True`

Comment: Hahhaha, well it runs on windows and linux also, in ci/cd pipelines it would be on linux, didnt thought to specify tho, my bad